# Classification algorithm making only one partition file in C and crashing right after

Tags: c, sorting, memory-leaks, partitioning

I have a classification function that's supposed to create partition files with M records in each depending on the complete file size but only one partition file is being created and i can't find the problem.
This classification function uses functions that are already being used outside of it, and they seem to be returning the correct values and functioning the right way, such as tamanho_arquivo() that returns the number of records in the file.

```
int classificacao_interna_Func(int M) {
    FILE *arq = fopen(EMPLOYEE_FILE_PATH, "rb+");
    rewind(arq);

    int reg = 0;
    int nFunc = tamanho_arquivo(arq);
    printf("Debug: nFunc = %d\n", nFunc);
    int qtdParticoes = 0;
    int t = sizeof(TFunc);
    char nomeParticao[20];
(...)
}
```

Here, when printing the debug message, nFunc is returning 977 when its supposed to be 1000. In another one, it's returning 0 instead of 10.
This is tamanho_arquivo()

```
int tamanho_arquivo(FILE *arquivo) {
    if (arquivo == NULL) {
        perror("Erro ao abrir o arquivo");
        return -1; // Indica erro
    }

    fseek(arquivo, 0, SEEK_END); // Move o cursor para o final do arquivo
    long tamanho_total = ftell(arquivo); 

    if (tamanho_total == -1) {
        perror("Erro ao obter o tamanho do arquivo");
        fclose(arquivo);
        return -1;
    }

    int num_registros = tamanho_total / tamanho_registro();

    fclose(arquivo);
    return num_registros;
}
```

[tamanho_registro() simply returns sizeof(TFunc)]

When used to make searches and apply sorting algorithms, everything works right. Maybe i'm focusing on the wrong thing but that's what i'm being able to do right now.
Any ideas of what can be the problem with the classification function?

I've already revised all the functions, i'm sure the logic is right (crying emoji). The code worked until the natural selection was completed and crashed right after.
I'll put the complete code if it clarifies anything

```
int classificacao_interna_Func(int M) {
    FILE *arq = fopen(EMPLOYEE_FILE_PATH, "rb+");
    rewind(arq);

    int reg = 0;
    int nFunc = tamanho_arquivo(arq);
    printf("Debug: nFunc = %d\n", nFunc);
    int qtdParticoes = 0;
    int t = sizeof(TFunc);
    char nomeParticao[20];

    while (reg != nFunc) {

        TFunc *v[M];
        int i = 0;
        while (!feof(arq)) {
            fseek(arq, (reg) * t, SEEK_SET);
            v[i] = (TFunc*)malloc(sizeof(TFunc));
            fread(v[i], sizeof(TFunc), 1, arq);
            i++;
            reg++;
            if (i >= M) break;
        }

        if (i != M) {
            M = i;
        }

        // Seleção natural
        for (int j = 0; j < M / 2; j++) {
            int minIndex = j;
            int maxIndex = j;
            for (int k = j + 1; k < M - j; k++) {
                if (v[k]->cod < v[minIndex]->cod) {
                    minIndex = k;
                } else if (v[k]->cod > v[maxIndex]->cod) {
                    maxIndex = k;
                }
            }
            if (minIndex != maxIndex) {
                TFunc *temp = v[minIndex];
                v[minIndex] = v[j];
                v[j] = temp;

                if (maxIndex == j) {
                    maxIndex = minIndex;
                }

                temp = v[maxIndex];
                v[maxIndex] = v[M - j - 1];
                v[M - j - 1] = temp;
            }
            printf("Debug: Seleção Natural Funcionarios Finalizado\n");
        }

        // Cria arquivo de partição e faz a gravação
        sprintf(nomeParticao, "%s/partition%i.dat", PARTITIONS_PATH, qtdParticoes);

        FILE *q;

        if ((q = fopen(nomeParticao, "wb+")) == NULL) {
            printf("Erro ao criar arquivo de saída\n");
        } else {
            for (int i = 0; i < M; i++) {
                fseek(q, (i) * t, SEEK_SET);
                fwrite(v[i], sizeof(TFunc), 1, q);
            }
            fclose(q);
            qtdParticoes++;
        }
        for (int jj = 0; jj < M; jj++)
            free(v[jj]);

    //printf("Debug 2: Classificação Interna Funcionarios Finalizado\n");
    }

    NUM_PARTITIONS = qtdParticoes;
}
```

Comment: Edit the question to provide a [mre].

Comment: Why not do the simple and post something one could compile? You can consider https://pt.stackoverflow.com/ also, this one in portuguese...